# (Django) Admin datatable does not show data in the select field

Tags: python, django, admin

below is the issue I'm having:

[image]

The drug type column, which is a select field with specified options

```py
drug_types_list = (
    ('pills','PILLS'),
    ('pellets','PELLETS'),
    ('lozenges','LOZENGES'),
)
```

somehow did not show any data. Even though inside my Jquery Datatable everything displayed.

[image]

So I went to my **drugs/admin.py** and modified the code as followed:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
# local
from .models import Drug
from .forms import DrugForm

    
class DrugAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    fields = ('drug_type',) # added
    list_display = ['drug_id', 'name', 'drug_type', 'amount']
    form = DrugForm # added
    list_per_page = 20
    search_fields = ['drug_id', 'name', 'drug_type', 'brand', 'description']
admin.site.register(Drug, DrugAdmin)
```

I aslo changed the drug_type line inside my **drugs/forms.py** as followed:

```py
from django import forms
# local
from drugs.models import Drug
from .drug_types import drug_types_list

 
class DrugForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Drug  
        fields = [
            'drug_id', 'name', 'drug_type',
            'amount',
        ] 
        widgets = { 
            'drug_id': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control', 'data-val': 'true', 'data-val-required': 'Please enter drug id', }), 
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }), 
            'drug_type': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}, choices=drug_types_list), # modified
            'amount': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }), 
        }
```

but nothing worked so far.

**drugs/models.py**

Below is my drug model:

```py
from django.db import models
from .drug_types import drug_types_list


class Drug(models.Model):
    drug_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, error_messages={'unique':"This drug id has already been registered."})
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    drug_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=drug_types_list, default='pills', blank=True, null=True)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Can you help me with this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

what I see between the two tables, shows different data records, try adding below your model setup:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['....']
```

in the ordering list, match the order in the Jquery data table